# Are all macros in the Rust std library included in the prelude?

Tags: rust, macros

Are all macros in Rust's std library included in the [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html)? So is every macro in [this whole list](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/#macros) always usable without any `use` statements and without using the `std::` prefix?

If they all are included in the prelude; is this guaranteed to always be the case or can a macro in theory be added to the std library and be accessable only with `std::foo::macro_name!()`?

Comment: Macros don't follow same rules as functions or modules, no matter where they're defined, if you mark them as exportable, they all will live in base of crate, and will be accessible through `cratename::macroname!`. `std::prelude` docs don't even mention macros, so it's most likely that they're all imported automagically, as I don't think there's any point in nitpicking over what should be exported from std macros, either all, or nothing. That being said, what is rationale of this question? If you cannot access some macro, compiler will tell you.

Comment: @Shasahae What's wrong with trying to get to learn the interesting parts of the language better?

Comment: Which part of my question to your question imply that your question is wrong?

I'm just asking if you had any issues with it, after explaining that it's most likely that either all macros or none of them are exported if you can access them, while also mentioning that they're namespaced differently from typical things like types or modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard macros [are actually not in the prelude](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9a32ad0dd51f8451aa6e39d7e9ea89483cb8fcfa/src/libstd/prelude/v1.rs).

`rustc` automatically adds the following code on your crate:

```rust
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#![no_std]
#[prelude_import]
use ::std::prelude::v1::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std as std;
```

Because of `#[macro_use] extern crate std as std;`, all macros defined in the standard library marked with `#[macro_export]` are available without using `std::`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer again! :) What about the second part of my question; can there be a macro added to the standard library which doesn't use `#[macro_export]`, and thus is not usable without the `std::foo::` prefix?

Comment: @ruohola no, because without `macro_export` they are not accessible outside. `macro_export` is basically `pub` for macros.

Comment: Side note: you can actually find this expansion using the `cargo expand` subcommand.